# Is it possible to upload a file in hdfs to ftp?

Tags: scala

```
def uploadFile(ftpClient: FTPClient, localPath: String) = {
  println(s"uploadFile:localPath: $localPath")
  val localFile = new File(localPath)
  val fileName = localFile.getName
  println(s"uploading file ${localPath} to ftp file $fileName")
  val fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(localPath)
  val uploadStatus = ftpClient.storeFile(fileName, fileInputStream)
  println(s"upload status of file $fileName = $uploadStatus")
  fileInputStream.close()
  uploadStatus
}
```

This is through local file not through hdfs .

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `InputStream` to read your HDFS file as follows:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}

val path: Path = // ...
val conf: Configuration = // ...
val inStream: InputStream = FileSystem.get(conf).open(path)
```

And continue similarly to what you've done with the local file. Of course, this will stream all data through the machine executing this code, so even if the file is distributed, the upload would be single-threaded.